# skip columns in read.table without knowing how many columns

Tags: r

So i know you can skip columns with read.table by providing a NULL to colClasses vector, but this is usually only helpful if you know how many columns are in your table.

What if I want to skip first 2 columns of table but read all the rest (which I know are numeric). Something like:

```
colClasses = c(NULL,NULL,rep("numeric", k))
```

except I don't know what k is. What would be best way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the default white-space separation on a file named "fil.txt" then use this

```
 colClasses = c(NULL,NULL,rep("numeric", count.fields("fil.txt")[1] -2 ))
```

If you use a different separator then something like

```
 colClasses = c(NULL,NULL,rep("numeric", count.fields("fil.txt", sep=",")[1] -2 ))
```

Comment: That's reading the whole file which seems pretty costly when you just need to look at the header. Also I think you are missing a minus two. I feel something like `length(scan(file, n=1))` would be faster than `count.fields(file)[1]`.

Comment: Yes. The minus 2 is needed, and I suppose  you could use `length( read.table(..., sep=sep, nrows=5 ))`

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to skip the first two columns:

```
data <- read.table("dataname.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")[,-c(1,2)]
```